# Adjusting the xaxis bar chart in plotly to the x-axis makes the Timeseries closer together

Tags: python-3.x, charts, plotly, plotly-dash

I have timeserière data which is X axis and value axis is y axis , but in x axis data, there are only 4 times per day in 1 day so when showing in chart bar there is a lot of distance, I want the columns to be closer to each other. , how do I do that in Bar plotly

```
fig = px.bar(x = concat_df_hop.index, y = concat_df_hop['CHANGE'], color=concat_df_hop['LABEL'],text=concat_df_hop['CHANGE_DICT'],color_discrete_map={

'Arbitrum':'#37c6f4',
'Optimsm':'#7e2779',
'Polygon':'#028480',

})
fig.update_layout(font=dict(size=10),template="plotly_white")
fig.update_xaxes(rangeselector_font_color='#000000',# rangeslider_visible=True,
                 ticks= "outside",
                 ticklabelmode= "period", 
                 ticklen=12,
              
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1, label="1D", step="day", stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=7, label="1W", step="day", stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1,label="1M", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=3,label="3M", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1, label="YTD", step="year", stepmode="todate"),
                dict(count=1, label="1y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
        ])
    )  )
fig.update_yaxes(gridwidth=1,mirror="ticks",showgrid=True,title="Value")
fig.update_layout(  legend=dict(
            orientation="h",
            # entrywidth=70,
            yanchor="middle",
            y=-0.3,
            xanchor="center",
            x=0.5,
        ),margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=10, b=20))
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate ='%{label:label}'+ '<br>%{text}',textposition = "outside")
fig.update_layout(   
    paper_bgcolor='#F2F3F4',
    plot_bgcolor='#F2F3F4')
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified",font=dict(size=10))
```

[image]

I want to ouput [image]